# Is there a good library in .NET for Parsing/Displaying ICS feeds?

Tags: asp.net, dotnetnuke, icalendar

I'd like to embed a google calendar in my website, but I hate the options their built in stuff gives me for colors, etc.

Has anyone put together a good library for doing this stuff.  I am specifically running on a DotNetNuke site, but any embeddable js code, or .NET library for doing this would be a great answer.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I've used [DDay.iCal](http://www.ddaysoftware.com/Pages/Projects/DDay.iCal/). It's pretty good. It used to have some flaky issues with recurring events, but I think those have been worked out.